# How to remove "For regular browsing... Download Chrome" info message while running selenium webdriver scripts on Selenium Grid

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

While running script on Selenium Grid - Remote Server seeing below info message all the time.

```
Selenium Grid Jar: selenium-server-4.12.1.jar

$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.12

$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 117.0.5938.62 (25a7172909a4cba7355365cf424d7d7eb35231f4-refs/branch-heads/5938@{#1146})
```

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
         "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
         "safebrowsing.enabled": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
caps = options.to_capabilities()
wd = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=remote_hub_address, options=options)
```

Any way to remove this message?

[Info Message ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWDDv.png)